# Convert nested form fields to JSON in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to do POST of Form object as JSON from front end javacsript/jquery to Spring MVC backend. 
Form data has a string array and other string field, looks like below

```
...
var cityList = [];
citylist.push("SF");
citylist.push("LA");
document.forms["myForm"]["dstCities"].value = cityList;
document.forms["myForm"]["dstState"].value = "CA";
...
```

Below is my code for converting to JSON,

```
function convertFormToJSON(){
    var jsonObject = {};
    var array = $("myForm").serializeArray();

    $.each(array, function() {
        if (jsonObject[this.name] !== undefined) {
            jsonObject[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            jsonObject[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });

    jsonObject = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    console.log("json: " + jsonObject);
    return jsonObject;
};
```

POST call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "xxx",
        type: "POST",
        data: convertFormToJSON(),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
   });
```

Json output:

```
{"dstCities":"SF,LA", "dstState":"CA"}
```

But I need it to look like

```
[{"dstCities": ["SF", "LA"], "dstState":"CA"}]
```

Comment: It looks like your data is being transformed here `document.forms["myForm"]["dstCities"].value = cityList;` from an array to a string.

Comment: I had tried,
document.forms["myForm"]["dstCities"] = cityList;
But this was assigning only first city in the list..

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array as value to :

```
document.forms["myForm"]["dstCities"].value = cityList;
```

but the browser is using `toString()` on it and it ends up as joined string `"SF,LA"`

If the intent is to pass it as string array can do:

```
document.forms["myForm"]["dstCities"].value = JSON.stringify(cityList);
```

No changes would be needed in convertFormToJSON this way.

---

If the cities need to be displayed as comma separated values then change

```
   if (jsonObject[this.name] !== undefined) {
       jsonObject[this.name].push(this.value || '');
   } else {
       var value = this.value;
       if (this.name === 'dstCities') {
           value = value.split(',');
       }
       jsonObject[this.name] = value || '';
   }
```

Comment: Using JSON.stringify(cityList) it was able to get as array string, 
but output now looks like 
{"dstCities": [\"SF\", \"LA\"], 
Any means to get rid of this extra slashes